# Docker ERROR: Volume specifies nonexistent driver inmemory

Tags: go, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

According to the docs there is a 'inmemory' driver for docker volumes:
https://docs.docker.com/registry/storage-drivers/inmemory/

> For purely tests purposes, you can use the inmemory storage driver.
>   This driver is an implementation of the storagedriver.StorageDriver
>   interface which uses local memory for object storage.

But when trying to use it like so:

```
volumes:
  ui-tmp-memory:
    driver: inmemory
```

It gives me this output:

```
Creating volume "myapp_ui-tmp-memory" with inmemory driver
ERROR: Volume ui-tmp-memory specifies nonexistent driver inmemory
```

Am I missing something or do I need to install "inmemory" driver somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you've provided points to [storage drivers for Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/storage-drivers/inmemory/). You seem to want to mount a volume in a container which would require a [Docker Engine Volume Plugin](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins/). These are two distinct types of plugins for two different applications and aren't interchangeable.

You may be able to easily accomplish what you want by creating a RAM disk and using the Local Persist Plugin in Docker Engine.

Comment: Hi @Kel Cecil and thanks for you post. Yeah was my oversight, thought this is part of the docker core.